# Having issues installing Hibernate3 on Debian Server

Tags: java, linux, hibernate, debian

I am attempting to install `Hibernate3` onto my linux server but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do to get it to work.  I have tried the following:

- copy required jars into a folder and called the folder via "`java -classpath etc.`" and got

> java -classpath /home/mcmaster/javalibs/* -jar craftbukkit.jar
>   Error: Could not find or load main class .home.mcmaster.javalibs.dom4j-1.6.1.jar

- load the java command while calling only the core hibernate which resulted in normal class not found error
- on a whim installed to system java lib location with no affect
- used `apt-get to install libhibernate3-java` with no change
- I have attempted to `export $CLASSPATH=~/javalibs` which has all the required jars

I'm literally pulling my hair out as an intermediate java user trying to learn some more advanced things(to me).

Here's the error I'm getting when trying to call the Session Class:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session

Comment: [Dontfollowthis](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/where-to-download-how-to-install-hibernate/) here it has required jar lists in it .

Comment: I've got the files.  Just seems like I'm not putting them in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the quotation marks. Try
`java -classpath '.:/home/mcmaster/javalibs/*' -jar craftbukkit.jar` (as seen on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Adding_all_JAR_files_in_a_directory)).

EDIT: I am guessing that craftbukkit.jar is executable.

Comment: So it did load the directory without error. But still getting class not found... Here is output of the directory I'm setting as classpath: